# how to get all user details (user name at least) who had logged in windows computer over a date range

Tags: python

I have a requirement to get all users who logged in a windows computer over a date range (let say for last 7 days). Is there a pythonic way to do that?
I have found below on SOF on researching

```
from subprocess import check_output
import sys

get_result = check_output("wmic netlogin get name, fullname, lastlogon", shell=True, stderr=False)

print(get_result)

clean_result = str(get_result).lstrip("b'").rstrip("'").replace("\\r\\r\\n", "\n").replace('\n\n', '\n').split('\n')[2:-1]

for items in clean_result:

    print(items.lstrip().rstrip())
```

but it doesn't provide date range option.

Answer (score 0):

This will be 2 step process:

1) Enable Logon Auditing:
    This link will help you with that : https://www.howtogeek.com/124313/how-to-see-who-logged-into-a-computer-and-when/
    The above link mentions that Logon events are registered with "event ID 4624", remember this.

2) Matching up start and stop session events (Optional):
    The thing is in windows every event is individually logged, so incase you wanna track both login and loggoff then you need do this step.
    This link will help you with that : https://4sysops.com/archives/track-windows-user-login-history/#matching-up-start-and-stop-session-events
    The above link also mentions a PowerShell script to do this activity.

3) Querying Windows events using python:
    Now query windows events for the "event id" mentioned in step 1 for whatever range of dates you like.
    You can using this link for that : https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/07/27/pywin32-getting-windows-event-logs/

I know this isn't a direct how-to but, I hope this helps in finding your way.